# If statements operating with a 3x3 array not operating properly

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

So I have a function that uses if statements and has the parameter of a 3x3 array (in python 3.3.5)

```
def checkDiagonals (game_board):
      match = 0
      if game_board[0][0]==game_board[1][1] and game_board[0][1]==game_board[2][2] and game_board[1][1]==game_board[2][2]: #checks if diagonals equal each other
                  match = game_board[0][0]
                  if match == " ":
                        match = "NO WINNER"

      match = 0
      if game_board[0][2]==game_board[1][1] and game_board[0][2]==game_board[2][0]: 
                  match = game_board[0][0]
                  if match == " ":
                        match = "NO WINNER"
      return (match)
```

The problem is,

```
print (checkDiagonals([["X", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]))
```

yields X, when it should yield 0 or NO WINNER. Does anyone want to give me a hint as to why this is so? I just don't see it.

Comment: The second `if` evaluates to `True`. The anti-diagonal are all the same `" "`. The problem is that you set `match = game_board[0][0]` afterward, when you should set `match = game_board[0][2]` (I think...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through the second half of your function.

```
match = 0
if game_board[0][2]==game_board[1][1] and game_board[0][2]==game_board[2][0]: 
    match = game_board[0][0]
    if match == " ":
        match = "NO WINNER"
return (match)
```

First, `match = 0`. This unconditionally resets `match` to 0. That's a red flag, because it overwrites whatever the result of the first half was.

Next, the `if` statement.

```
  if game_board[0][2]==game_board[1][1] and game_board[0][2]==game_board[2][0]:
```

If we substitute in the values of those board positions, we get:

```
if " "==" " and " "==" ":
```

All of the positions being checked are spaces. The `if` statement succeeds. That means we proceed to the following assignment.

```
    match = game_board[0][0]
```

Well the value of position 0,0 is "X". This is equivalent to:

```
    match = "X"
```

This is why `match` ends up as "X". The followup check `if match == " "` fails, so nothing else happens. `match` remains "X" rather than "NO WINNER".

---

Walking through the code step by step revealed at least two problems. One is that `match` is overwritten, so the results of the first diagonal check are lost. Another is that it grabs the letter from the wrong square.